# Can't initialize rosdep after installing ROS through conda-forge

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, installation, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

#### Issue:

I installed ros-melodic through conda-forge.

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
conda create --name ros --channel conda-forge ros-core ros-actionlib ros-dynamic-reconfigure ros-roslib python=3.6
```

however when trying to initialize rosdep within the newly created `ros` environment, it rightfully denies the permissions to /etc/ros/ folder in the root:

```
ERROR: cannot create /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d:
    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/ros'
```

And when writing `sudo rosdep init` it give same error: `sudo: rosdep: command not found`, (though I think that's a [separate issue](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/745)).

#### Question:

I don't know where else to ask this but uhm, what do I need to change so that `rosdep` stays within the conda environment folders and doesn't try to modify root folders?

Details about  `conda` and system ( `conda info` ):
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS,
[conda-forge / packages / ros-roslib 1.14.6](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ros-roslib)

```
(ros) jek@jek-u18-04-4lts:~$ conda info

     active environment : ros
    active env location : /home/jek/anaconda3/envs/ros
        shell level : 2
       user config file : /home/jek/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/jek/.condarc
      conda version : 4.8.3
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
     python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=9.1
                      __glibc=2.27
       base environment : /home/jek/anaconda3  (writable)
       channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
      package cache : /home/jek/anaconda3/pkgs
                      /home/jek/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/jek/anaconda3/envs
                      /home/jek/.conda/envs
           platform : linux-64
         user-agent : conda/4.8.3 requests/2.23.0 CPython/3.7.3 Linux/4.15.0-91-generic ubuntu/18.04.4 glibc/2.27
            UID:GID : 1000:1000
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347533/can%27t-initialize-rosdep-after-installing-ros-through-conda-forge/) by [Yev_D](https://answers.ros.org/users/52485/yev_d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's an issue here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/495

There was an attempted fix here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/pull/551

But it had to be rolled back: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/pull/584 due to https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/582

There's a new PR to resolve this here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/pull/583

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yev_D](https://answers.ros.org/users/52485/yev_d/) on 2020-03-25**:
ouf, that "new PR" is almost 2 yrs old.
Thanks for the links, though they are helpful to track this issue, I won't mark them as an answer yet since, well, since it doesn't resolve the original issue ^_^
Respectfully.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-03-25**:
The best answer to your direct question is the diff attached to the current PR under consideration.

Keeping this open in parallel with the known issue on the tracker isn't going to help get it resolved any sooner and anyone finding this issue should follow up there. Old questions here will just languish this is not an issue tracker that will be triaged and closed out. There's no more correct "answer" possible except to follow up back here when that the open issue has been closed. And based on past performance almost no one will follow up here on an old question to confirm that the other thread has been resolved. But if you want to commit to that it's fine.

**Comment by [Yev_D](https://answers.ros.org/users/52485/yev_d/) on 2020-03-25**:
Yeah, I see your point about not tracking an issue on this platform. That makes sens. I also agree with this question not having its answer for the lack of development for this particular issue. Your answer on git about a work around, that's interesting. Would you mind updating your answer here to include it. Because I'm stuck on this step and not sure what to do.
You said that ppl just drop the source file into the root. Could you please specify where or how to write the file, or how does it look?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-03-25**:
rosdep init just fetches [this file](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/blob/73dd9917b12b69d7e6c08a4f57fa70ce86372f1e/src/rosdep2/sources_list.py#L69) and drops it at `/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list`

```
$ cat /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list 
# os-specific listings first
yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml osx

# generic
yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml
yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml
yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
gbpdistro https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml fuerte

# newer distributions (Groovy, Hydro, ...) must not be listed anymore, they are being fetched from the rosdistro index.yaml instead
```

**Comment by [Yev_D](https://answers.ros.org/users/52485/yev_d/) on 2020-03-27**:
@tfoote, hey, just wanted to clarify this. Here is what I did, is this correct?

1. Create folder "/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list/"

   `sudo mkdir /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list`
2. Drop the sources_list.py into this folder

   `cp /home/jek/Downloads/sources_list.py /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list`

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-03-27**:
No it's not the file source code file for processing the list but the data file referenced at that line in the file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list that should be put there.

**Comment by [Yev_D](https://answers.ros.org/users/52485/yev_d/) on 2020-03-28**:
@tfoote, that didn't work. I'll just install a separate Uubuntu dedicated for ROS, for now.